# Типы целочисленных литералов в MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В стандарте языка говорится, что десятичный целочисленный литерал без суффикса должен иметь первый тип из списка: `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, который может представить значение этого литерала.

Однако, попытка компиляции такого кода:

```
    int a = -2147483648;
```

в MS Visual Studio 2010 с 32-битными `int`'ом и `long`'ом, и 64-битным `long long`'ом приводит к появлению предупреждения "C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned".

[Справка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4146), говорит, что литерал `2147483648`, слишком велик, чтобы поместиться в `int`, и потому он имеет тип `unsigned int`. Но ведь согласно стандарту в данной ситуации литерал `2147483648` должен иметь тип `long long`!

Почему в довольно таки простой ситуации в Visual Studio реализовано поведение, прямо противоречащее стандарту???
Исправлено ли это в более поздних версиях Visual Studio?
Такое поведение распространено среди других компиляторов?

Answer (score 1):

**gcc version 7.1.0** при таком коде

```
 #include <iostream>                          

 template<typename T>                         
 void getType(T t){                           
     std::cout << "T" << std::endl;           
 }                                            

 void getType(int t){                         
     std::cout << "int" << std::endl;         
 }                                            

 void getType(unsigned int t){                
     std::cout << "unsigned int" << std::endl;
 }                                            

 void getType(long int t){                    
     std::cout << "long int" << std::endl;    
 }                                            

 int main(){                                  
     int a = -2147483648;            

     getType(a);                              
     getType(-2147483648);                    

     return 0;                                
 }
```

выдает

```
int
long int
```

без всяких варнингов